# Как сделать перевернутый параллелограмм средствами CSS?

Tags: css, css3

В интернете полно гайдов как сделать параллелограмм, но нигде нет перевернутого параллелограмма, посидел пару часов ничего не получается, может Вы подскажите, буду очень благодарен! На картинке черным цветом нарисовано как бы контейнер сайта, а синим параллелограммы что мне надо, приблизительно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, если хочешь делать что-то подобное, как у тебя на картинке, лучше всего использовать изображения, что бы создать визуальный наклон, дабы не грузить браузер бесполезным рендерингом и не усложнять вёрстку. Но ежели тебе невмоготу, то держи простую реализацию

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  transform: skew(10deg) rotate(10deg) translateY(-40px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4px;
}


.top-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110%;
  transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(-10deg) translateY(40px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}


.middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  transform: skew(10deg) rotate(10deg) translateY(-40px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


.middle-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110%;
  transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(-10deg) translateY(40px);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}


.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  transform: skew(10deg) rotate(10deg) translateY(-40px);
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: table;
}


.bottom-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110%;
  transform: skew(-10deg) rotate(-10deg) translateY(-50px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="top-inner">
      Текст 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="middle-inner">
      Текст 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="bottom-inner">
      Текст 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь и проделанную работу, не ожидал такой отдачи) Ваш вариант мне больше всего понравился, если не считать, что он громоздкий, но есть тот же минус что и у всех, когда поставить ширину родителя на 100%, все плывет, а мне резина как бы й надо. Будем считать Ваш ответ лучшим, все таки буду использовать картинку для фона. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @JackLondon Не за что. Если хочешь резиновый вариант таких наклонов, то однозначно лучше делать изображениями. Я как-то делал небольшой лендинг — http://eauthor.ru — там что-то похожее, можешь поизучать стили

Comment: да, в Вашей работе eauthor описан вообще идеальный вариант, буду ним пользоваться) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для свойства transform укажите две функции: наклон и поворот

```
transform: skew(20deg) rotate(90deg);
```

или укажите явный наклон по оси Y:

```
transform: skewY(20deg);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, Ваш вариант очень похож на вариант выше.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#parallelogram {
  margin-top: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-15deg);
  transform: skewY(15deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="parallelogram"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, пробовал такой вариант, но когда ширина контейнера 100%, то получается не очень, даже если все с позиционировать, то текст внутри блока тоже с наклоном.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, но для проф-применения нужно делать по другому, [SVG](https://svg-art.ru/)

```css
SVG {
  display: block;
}
.svg-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#svg2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
}
#svg3 {
  position: relative;
  top: -120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg id="" style="width:300px;height:100px;">
    <polygon points="0,0 0,30 300,100 300,0 " style="fill: yellow; fill-opacity:1; stroke:blue;" />
  </svg>
  <svg id="svg2" style="width:300px;height:200px;">
    <polygon points="0,0 300,70 300,130 0,200" style="fill: yellow; fill-opacity:1; stroke:blue;" />
  </svg>
  <svg id="svg3" style="width:300px;height:100px;">
    <polygon points="0,100  300,100 300,0 0,70" style="fill: yellow; fill-opacity:1; stroke:blue;" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Как я понял, он хочет делать таким образом структуру сайта, т.е. проще говоря в твоём примере внутри svg-полигонов у него должен оказаться html

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz    Всё что угодно можно засунуть в SVG

Comment: Хм, и правда. Попробовал, сработало, не задавался этим вопросом никогда. Но правильная ли такая реализация?

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz  нет, ни верная это структура, я же написал что "для проф-применения нужно делать по другому" , на ruSO не учат но могут оказать помощь если что то не получится, я показал пример что так сделать реально , дальше дело Автора вопроса, что он сделал для того что бы продвинутся ?!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, автор вопроса только потратил 5 часов на гуглеж...